# CLI tool splits AVI file with JPEG format video

Tags: video, video-processing

I'm a newbie in video processing, and I'm trying to write a program in Python.
The program is to split a long video into some short videos by timestamp.

For example, I have an input, `video long_video.avi`, which is 15 minutes long. 
I want extract to 2 videos, `short_1_5_video.avi` (1'-5') and `short_6_10_video.avi` (6'-10').
The input video has container `AVI` and video format `JPEG`.
This is information of video (show in mediainfo tool):

[image]

I want find a CLI (command line interface) tool which I can invoke from Python.
I tried some tools:

- `mp4box`(http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box):

  But mp4box not support AVI file. It only supports MKV and MP4 file.
- `mkvmerge`(in mkv tool):

  But mkvmerge only supports MKV file.
- `ffmgeg`:

  But It seem not support split video by timestamp("seem" because I didn't find It 
  in specification of ffmpeg).

I thought about convert input video from `AVI` to `MP4` or `MKV` and then splitting it, but the time taken to do the conversion is too long.
Please suggest me a tool can splits `AVI` file with `JPEG` format video that can be controlled from the command line.

In addition, I also want to find a GUI tool that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to split this file into 3 parts: `beginning -> 00:00:05 -> 00:00:10 -> end`, try this:

```
mencoder -endpos 00:00:05 -oac copy -ovc copy input.avi -o part1.avi
mencoder -ss 00:00:05 -oac copy -ovc copy input.avi -o tmp.avi

mencoder -endpos 00:00:10 -oac copy -ovc copy tmp.avi -o part2.avi
mencoder -ss 00:00:10 -oac copy -ovc copy tmp.avi -o part3.avi
```

Comment: Why wouldn't he just use the `-ss` and `-endpos` options in conjunction to do it in a single line (as the link in my answer illustrates)

Comment: Thanks quanta. It very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use `ffmpeg` (`-ss` in seconds or hh:mm:ss format for start position and `-t` in seconds of hh:mm:ss format for length/duration).

[`mencoder`](http://bro1.centras.info/mencoder_editing.html) (part of mplayer) also seems like it would work.  I linked not to the mplayer/mencoder site, but rather to a page that had command line options for mencoder that might help.

I believe `vlc` would also work (`--start-time <time in seconds> --stop-time <time in seconds> --sout <output file>`)